# How to use absolute path instead of class path to read files

Tags: automated-tests, karate

I want to store all my resources file/scripts/payload in one package & through call function, I want to read that file or scripts. To use classpath in this scenario is creating a problem.

In karate config, I'm setting a variable as application_path with an absolute path which I'm referring in a feature file

Karate config

```
{
application_path:"/home/local/IdeaProjects/project/src/test/java/module"
}
```

can anyone please help how to set or use an absolute path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is of course not at all recommended, but we support the `file:` prefix for absolute paths.

Please refer to the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#reading-files

```
* def payload = read('file:/home/foo/bar.json')
```

Comment: I have my resources file in another package whose absolute path I use to read js scripts or file.`* def createFeatureDiscount = applicationPath + '/discount/externalService/createDiscountForExternalCall.feature'
    * def readFetchupdate = callonce read(createFeatureDiscount)`

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say - and I don't have any more suggestions besides what I have answered. finally you always have the option to call custom java code, return a string (or Map) and do whatever you want - please refer the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java

Comment: As i wanted to have system path  `java.lang.System.getProperty("user.dir")` did the trick